# Groovy way of grouping by more than one property only one level deep

Tags: groovy

I want to group by 3 properties but not have each property be it's own nested array. What I want:

```
 def values=[
     [day:1,month:1,year:1],
     [day:1,month:1,year:1],
     [day:2,month:1,year:1],
     [day:2,month:2,year:1]
 ];

 /*...some code to group by DAY, MONTH, AND YEAR

 ..desired result is that items with the same day, 
  month, and year end up in a one level deep subarray
 */

  [
    [[day:1,month:1,year:1],[day:1,month:1,year:1]],  
    [[day:2,month:1,year:1]] ,
    [[day:2,month:2,year:1]] 
  ];
```

Using the **groupBy()** method with multiple closures gives me each grouped property as its own nested array, like [ year [ month [ day [ ] ] ]  ], which is **not what I need.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following use of `inject` to build up a map whose keys are the appropriate group, and values are the desired lists:

(**Edit**: *updated construction of the map key, per comment*)

```
def values=[
     [day:1,month:1,year:1],
     [day:1,month:1,year:1],
     [day:2,month:1,year:1],
     [day:2,month:2,year:1]
 ];

def groupMap = [:].withDefault{ key -> [] }

def result = values.inject(groupMap) { val, m -> 
    val["${m.'day'}:${m.'month'}:${m.'year'}"] << m 
    val
}.values()

assert [[day:1, month:1, year:1], [day:1, month:1, year:1]] == result[0]
assert [[day:2, month:1, year:1]] == result[1]
assert [[day:2, month:2, year:1]] == result[2]
```

Comment: a call to .groupBy({...}) followed by .values() would also lead to the same result.

Comment: also, be sure to double check the "key" pattern used for grouping. this example uses a simple string (fair enough to show the concept), but january 11th and november 1st would be indistinguishable (if the input values really are like the question states simple integers)

Comment: re: indistinguishable keys. Good point. I've updated the key construction for the map so that it is slightly more robust.

Answer (score 2):

You want to adopt your groupBy function to just do what you need.  In this example your maps there are already the identity you want to group them with.  So this is enough for the result you are looking for:

```
def values=[
    [day:1,month:1,year:1],
    [day:1,month:1,year:1],
    [day:2,month:1,year:1],
    [day:2,month:2,year:1],
]

// just the identity
println values.groupBy().values()
// => [[[day:1, month:1, year:1], [day:1, month:1, year:1]], [[day:2, month:1, year:1]], [[day:2, month:2, year:1]]]
```

And if you do actually have more values in your maps there, you can use a `subMap` to group to one level:

```
// submap only the needed keys (in case there is more in `values` than just your identity
println values.groupBy{ it.subMap(["year","month","day"]) }.values()
// => [[[day:1, month:1, year:1], [day:1, month:1, year:1]], [[day:2, month:1, year:1]], [[day:2, month:2, year:1]]]
```

On the nitpicking side: those are nested maps your get.